# attach a role to an existing EC2 instance, using cloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

it's all said in the title

I'm looking to attach a role to an EC2 instance already created, using cloudFormation.

I want to know if it's possible with cloudformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is possible:**

1. You need an [`AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) in your resources section
   where you can reference the role ARN.
2. And then you can use [`IamInstanceProfile`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) property in your EC2 instance to reference the instance profile resource you created

Comment: even if my EC2 instance is not created in the same cloudformation Template ?
How can i relate [IamInstanceProfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) if i'm not creating the instance in the same Template ?

Comment: That's a different question btw. Yes you can, but then you'll have to export the arn of your role from one template and use it in the other by using the intrinsic import function. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html

Comment: Hey @hamza. If this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.